# NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '-' was called on null

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

here is my code. i cant find where is the problem.

problem:Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '-' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: -(null))[image]

```html
class CartScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Product> cartItems;
  CartScreen(this.cartItems);
  @override
  _CartScreenState createState() => _CartScreenState();
}

class _CartScreenState extends State<CartScreen> {
  double _total;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getTotal();
  }

  _getTotal() {
    _total = 0.0;
    this.widget.cartItems.forEach((item) {
      setState(() {
        _total += (item.price - item.discount) * item.quantity;
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: looks like the item fields are null, are you using nullable variables inside the Product class? if yes then make sure that all the fields are initialized

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the data itself, it looks like one of your `Product` items is probably missing a value for its `discount` property. You can print the values in the `forEach` loop to confirm if that's the case.

As a side note, you can optimize your code a bit in a few ways:

1. Instantiate the `_total` variable: `double _total = 0;`
2. In the `_getTotal` method, you should either move the `setState` call to encompass the `forEach` loop `(a)`, or have it called once, after the loop is finished `(b)`. Doing it the way you have it currently will cause the widget to "refresh" the state for each item, which may not be what you want.

```dart
// Variation (a)
void _getTotal() {
  setState(() {
  this.widget.cartItems.forEach((item) {
      _total += (item.price - item.discount) * item.quantity;
    });
  });
}

// Variation (b)
void _getTotal() {
  this.widget.cartItems.forEach((item) {
      _total += (item.price - item.discount) * item.quantity;
    });

  setState((){});
}
```